# Initialse a jsonArray java

Tags: android, json

I am trying to initiale a json a jsonArray but i am lost in doing it.

Where am i wrong and how do we initiale a json array

```
JSONArray template = 
            {
                  "header": "Colors",
                  "items": [
                      {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
                      {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
                      {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
                  ],
                  "empty": false
                };
```

Comment: the above is a jsonobject having one JSONArray "items".

Comment: json array starts with[ and ends ]

Comment: First, that's a JSONObject, as comments already said.  Secondly, you need to new the object-  you can't create a java object like that.

Comment: i don't get your point

Comment: @yakusha this is jsonobject and it has a json array, you want like this then initialize it as jsonobject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `JSONObject` of the template mentioned, which will automatically initialize the `items`.

```
try {
    String template = "{\"header\": \"Colors\", " +
        "\"items\": [ " +
        "{\"name\": \"red\", \"first\": true, \"url\": \"#Red\"}, " +
        "{\"name\": \"green\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Green\"}, " +
        "{\"name\": \"blue\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Blue\"}" +
        " ], \"empty\": false }";

    JSONObject jsonWithArrayInIt = new JSONObject(template); //JSONObject created for the template.
    JSONArray items = jsonWithArrayInIt.getJSONArray("items"); //JSONArray of items present inside the JSONObject.
    System.out.println(items.toString());
} catch (JSONException je) {
    //Error while creating JSON.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the proper way to initialize an `JSONArray`

```
public class TestJSON {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONArray template = new JSONArray("[ {\"name\": \"red\", \"first\": true, \"url\": \"#Red\"}," +
            " {\"name\": \"green\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Green\"}," +
            "{\"name\": \"blue\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Blue\"} ]");

    System.out.println(template.toString());

    }
}
```

Following is the output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "red",
        "first": true,
        "url": "#Red"
    },
    {
        "link": true,
        "name": "green",
        "url": "#Green"
    },
    {
        "link": true,
        "name": "blue",
        "url": "#Blue"
    }
]
```

EDIT1:

You can use the following code to create your full JSON object..

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONArray template = new JSONArray(
            "[ {\"name\": \"red\", \"first\": true, \"url\": \"#Red\"},"
                + " {\"name\": \"green\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Green\"},"
                + "{\"name\": \"blue\", \"link\": true, \"url\": \"#Blue\"} ]");

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        object.put("header", "Colors");
        object.put("empty", false);
        object.put("items", template);

        System.out.println(object.toString());
        }
```

Following is the output:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "red",
            "first": true,
            "url": "#Red"
        },
        {
            "link": true,
            "name": "green",
            "url": "#Green"
        },
        {
            "link": true,
            "name": "blue",
            "url": "#Blue"
        }
    ],
    "empty": false,
    "header": "Colors"
}
```

EDIT2:

Following code can be used to generate the full JSON object without using string containing JSON data:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONArray template = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", "red");
    obj.put("first", true);
    obj.put("url", "#Red");
    template.put(obj);

    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    obj1.put("name", "green");
    obj1.put("link", true);
    obj1.put("url", "#Green");
    template.put(obj1);

    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
    obj2.put("name", "blue");
    obj2.put("link", true);
    obj2.put("url", "#Blue");
    template.put(obj2);

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("header", "Colors");
    object.put("empty", false);
    object.put("items", template);

    System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
```

Following is the output of this program:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "red",
            "first": true,
            "url": "#Red"
        },
        {
            "link": true,
            "name": "green",
            "url": "#Green"
        },
        {
            "link": true,
            "name": "blue",
            "url": "#Blue"
        }
    ],
    "empty": false,
    "header": "Colors"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of self formatting, I've been doing it with following way and it worked for me.

```
  function fillPolicydetails()
    {
    var clsPolicyDetails={}
      clsPolicyDetails.name="Sangeeta"
      clsPolicyDetails.technology=".net"
    return clsPolicyDetails;
    }




     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data:  "{'policydetail':" + JSON.stringify(fillPolicydetails())+"}",    //finally here's the magic:
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (Result) {
                    successFunction(Result);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    failureFunction(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

above code will generate json format for you and will send it as an object instead of raw strings

if any issues please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

if template is your json array means holding more than one value then initialize like this :

```
JSONArray template = new JSONArray("
        [{
              "header": "Colors",
              "items": [
                  {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
                  {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
                  {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
              ],
              "empty": false
            }]");
```

if items is json array and template is a json object holding items then do like this

```
JSONArray items=new JSONArray ("[
                      {"name": "red", "first": true, "url": "#Red"},
                      {"name": "green", "link": true, "url": "#Green"},
                      {"name": "blue", "link": true, "url": "#Blue"}
                  ]");


JSONObject template = new JSONObject();
template .put("sessionId",
                    new JSONString("Colors"));
template .put("items",
                    items);
template .put("empty",
                    new JSONBoolean(false));
```

Logic is correct sometimes its function name or class name will change according to different package. I am using `com.google.gwt.json.client`